# Schedule SSIS Through Web Application

Tags: ssis, scheduled-tasks

Does anyone know of a good way for a user to be able to specify the schedule for a SSIS package through a web application? The package will run once a day, but the user needs to be able to configure the time that it will run. i.e. every day @ 7am or every day @ 8am etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use SMO to manage the SQL Server Agent, which is what you use to schedule an SSIS package (or packages). Use the [JobServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobserver.aspx) object to get started.

You may want to create the job manually in SQL Server Management Studio, then just use SMO to adjust the schedule.

Comment: You can call the SSIS Package from Job Scheduler.